# When a C++ program terminates on Windows what is the last function called by the termination stub?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reverse-engineering

This question is about reverse engineering and the Microsoft Standard C Library.

When a C program terimates gracefully, i.e. does a  `return 0;` at the end of `main()`. What all happens (generalize please). **Specifically, what is the *last* function called by the C library?**

Comment: afaik main just returns and that's it...

Comment: Good question, but I guess you could write "hello world", put a breakpoint and inspect the call stack down to the program entry point.

Comment: @Tony: Well, at some point the program must ask the OS "end me please, sir" - something like ExitProcess().

Comment: Btw I believe the answer will be implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Sharptooth, but like you say, that will depend on what the OS does then to kill it, OP just asking about C library

Comment: @Tony: Sure, that's why I believe it is implementation-dependent and the right answer is "there's no standard function for that, that's library inner workings detail".

Comment: @sharptooth ExitProcess() is probably the answer I was looking for.. lemme check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the sources of the Microsoft CRT in "%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio x.0\VC\crt\src".

The entrypoint for executables (`mainCRTStartup`) is in crt0.c, or, in case the runtime DLL is used, in crtexe.c. You can see that after calling `main()` it calls `exit()`. The source code of `exit()` is in crt0dat.c. It calls C and C++ termination handlers (closing stdio handles etc), calls `atexit()` functions, and finally calls __crtExitProcess() which calls kernel32's **ExitProcess()**.

Comment: CRT source is not available in the express editions of Visual Studio.

Comment: True, but you didn't say you have Express edition. You can also install a trial version of full edition and check the source there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `strace` on your machine, you can use that (invoke it via `strace ./program`) - on my machine, with the following code, it gives `exit_group(0)` as the last function:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

As for what happens (warning: sweeping generalisations ahead), the operating system (theoretically) should attempt to start reclaiming memory from your process by deleting all memory you've left new'd.

Comment: It does exist under cygwin, but it's not too much trouble to get working if the OP is looking into reverse engineering anyway.

Comment: Also, the analogous tool under windows is StraceNT - http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=strace.htm

Comment: A normal OS won't bother "deleting all memory you've left new'd". It doesn't even care. That's because `new` is between you and the runtime. The OS just provides chunks of raw memory to your process, and reclaims those. In particular, it won't run destructors (which `delete` does).

Comment: Yeah, perhaps the word delete was misleading. I meant it not in terms of the operator delete, but in terms of removal....

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the exact same question, and have found my answer. Strongly hope I am not wrong, but I will go with the "numbers don't lie" principle.

The latter when a process shutsdown would be this:

```
ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess -> ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess -> msvcrt!__crtExitProcess -> msvcrt!doexit -> msvcrt!exit
```

From all my tests regardless of the exit reason (graceful, error, exception) these are called.

You can rely on **LdrShutdownProcess** only, no need to go deeper.

Best of luck!